# Lispbuilder-SDL: turn surface and preserve color key (transparency)

Tags: common-lisp, sdl, sbcl, sdl-image

## Explanation

I'm writing turtle graphics app in CL using SDL. I've created a drawing of a turtle and saved it in PNG. Snag No 1: `SDL:LOAD-IMAGE` didn't work well with actual transparency in the image. So, I've colored transparent parts with white color and did

```
(sdl:load-image
 (merge-pathnames #P"resources/turtle.png"
                  (asdf:system-source-directory :cl-turtle))
 :image-type :png
 :color-key sdl:*white*)
```

So, `:COLOR-KEY` option says that all `SDL:*WHITE*` pixels will be transparent. And this works: drawing the turtle on the yellow background showed no white pixels.

However, I would like my turtle to point into a particular direction and change it in the response to `TURN` command. One suggestion I've found was to use the sprites for all possible angles, but this won't work nicely for the turtle: too many directions.

So, I've loaded `LISPBUILDER-SDL-GFX`, to use `SDL:ROTATE-SURFACE-XY`. And it does rotate the the turtle fine. And I can see, that `SDL:*WHITE*` is set as color-key and color-keying is enabled in the rotated surface. However, when I draw it, white color is still rendered. Is there a way to fix this?

## Full code

```
(ql:quickload '(:lispbuilder-sdl :lispbuilder-sdl-image :lispbuilder-sdl-gfx :vom))

(defstruct turtle
  direction
  x
  y
  scale)

(defun draw-turtle (turtle image)
  ;; (format t "~&GFX? ~A~%" lispbuilder-sdl-cffi::*gfx-loaded-p*)
  (let ((img (sdl:rotate-surface-xy (mod (turtle-direction turtle) 360)
                                    :surface image)))
    (setf (sdl::color-key img) sdl:*white*)
    (setf (sdl:color-key-enabled-p img) t)
    (vom:info "Color key enabled (img)?: ~A" (sdl:color-key-enabled-p img))
    (vom:info "Color key is: ~A" (slot-value (sdl:color-key img) 'sdl::color-vector))
    (sdl:draw-surface-at-* img
                           (turtle-x turtle)
                           (turtle-y turtle))))

(defun turtle ()
  (sdl:with-init()
    (sdl:window 500 500
                :title-caption "Turtle")
    (setf (sdl:frame-rate) 1)
    (let ((turtle-image (sdl:load-image
                         (merge-pathnames #P"resources/turtle.png"
                                          (asdf:system-source-directory :cl-turtle))
                         :image-type :png
                         :color-key sdl:*white*))
          (turtle (make-turtle :direction 30 :x 200 :y 200 :scale 1)))
     (sdl:with-events ()
       (:quit-event () t)
       (:key-down-event () (sdl:push-quit-event))
       (:idle ()
              (sdl:clear-display sdl:*yellow*)
              (draw-turtle turtle turtle-image)
              (sdl:update-display))))))

(turtle)
```

## Log(VOM) output

```
  <INFO> [14:24:35] cl-turtle - Color key enabled (img)?: T
  <INFO> [14:24:35] cl-turtle - Color key is: #(255 255 255)
```

## Screenshot

[image: Turtle screenshot]

## System info

Ubuntu 16.04 with libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.4, libSDL_gfx.so.15.9.1 and libSDL_image-1.2.so.0.8.4

SBCL 1.3.7 (from roswell sbcl-bin)

Comment: Instead of color keying, you might have more luck with directly using PNG with transparent background and alpha blending (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72755/when-should-i-use-color-keying-vs-png-transparency). I'll try to see if I can make an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, calling `sdl:load-and-convert-image` instead of `sdl:load-image` fixes the issue.

> Loads an image from the filename SOURCE as per LOAD-IMAGE-*, converts
>   this image to the current display format using SDL:CONVERT-SURFACE.
>
> Parameters supported are the same as those for LOAD-IMAGE and
>   SDL:CONVERT-IMAGE.

Comment: @mobiuseng Sorry, I don't know much about SDL and inspecting both  surfaces (load vs. load+convert) does not give much indication. This requires a little more research.

Comment: I see. This was also confusing for me. Main point: it works! I can focus on actual turtle graphics now. Thanks!